# Adding a company logo for every account page

Tags: formula, account, page-layout

Can somebody tell me how to add a logo on an account page? So that when I go to my customer page layout named Coca-Cola (for instance), the account owner and other users who can see this account will see their nice red logo.

I have checked on the `AppExchange` but I did not find anything.

Please *Keep It Stupid and Simple* when explaining as I am just an Administrator.

Comment: You can try this one https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5bTTEAZ

Answer (score 6):

Well if you use Lightning Experience you may be in luck. Summer 16 release notes just hit the interwebs and they have a new feature called `Account Logos (Beta)`.

**Visualize Your Business Like Never Before with Account Logos (Beta)**

> They say a picture is worth a thousand words, but there’s just one word to describe the fact company
>   logos are now shown on account records—awesome. This feature is available in Lightning Experience
>   and all versions of the Salesforce1 app.
>
> Note: This release contains a beta version of Account Logos that is production quality but
>   has known limitations.
>
> From Account Settings, select the option to allow logos. Voilà! Logos show up automatically, when
>   available, on US-based accounts. If you use Social Accounts, logos that reps added manually from
>   social networks may be replaced with a fresher, more up-to-date logo.

[image]

Comment: And we'll be using that to replace our own home brew system (finally!).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar solution, using custom VisualForce page as an inline visualforce page on page layout .

For example it may look like this:

[image: Visualforce banner]

But there two questions which must be answered:

1. where you will plan to store images for each account?
2. how you will plan to associate account record to specific image?

In my solution, we have not very much accounts, so we just put all images in static resource, and then retrieve required image in controller.

If you provide answers, I will try to help you with this.

Thanks.